How can I fix my AVD Android Emulator window in Android Studio?
I want to resize or normalize my window, but it looks like two parts. I want to see in one part the normal mobile phone appearance.
My Emulator View
I tried to change size with Ctrl + ▲ and Ctrl + ▼. Also, I tried to resize by dragging a corner. All of them not working for me.

Go to Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator -> check to Launch in the Running Devices tool window.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I solved the problem. In the emulator extended controls --> displays I have added secondary display before. So I removed secondary display. That's all.
Extended controls
